# catkin_make not running

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS Kinetic.

When I try to run catkin_make it gave the following error

```
The program 'catkin_make' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install catkin
```

when I run sudo apt install catkin it gave :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300689/catkin_make-not-running/) by [dhruvt](https://answers.ros.org/users/37003/dhruvt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-08-16**:
I can't help you but can anticipate questions coming. Please update the question with below info.
What hardware?
What version of operating system?
What method did you use to install, source or binaries?
Did you go through the tutorials line by line to start?
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/StartGuide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like you may have missed section 1.6 from the installation [instructions here](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu). Try executing the following command in your terminal before `catkin_make`

```
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

Add this command to your .bashrc file as described will mean that `catkin_make` will always be available in any terminal.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0